# Помогите написать два SQL запроса

Tags: sql, запрос

Целый день бьюсь - не могу написать запросы к заданиям 1 и 2. Помогите, пожалуйста.
[image: sql код]

Во втором задании получилось вывести только первые три столбца запросом:
    SELECT USER_NAME, MIN(EVENT_DATE), MAX(EVENT_CNT) FROM "D_STAT" WHERE     EVENT_CNT = (SELECT MAX(EVENT_CNT) FROM "D_STAT") GROUP BY USER_NAME ORDER BY USER_NAME

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(t1.numb), 0) + 1 num
FROM d_test t1
LEFT JOIN d_test t2 ON t1.numb = t2.numb - 1
WHERE t2.numb IS NULL;
```

> Во втором задании получилось вывести только первые три столбца

Теперь другим запросом получи столбцы 1,4 и 5, и свяжи эти выборки по первым столбцам.